# WCAG: Can I just link users to a high-contrast mode tool?

Tags: wcag

I'm on a project that needs to comply with Section 508 and WCAG 2.0, and we are going to support all the accessibility tags and everything just fine, but then I hit a snag with color contrasts... Trying to make all colors have enough contrast both with the text and background colors (to follow WCAG) as well as contrast compared to nearby items, I'm having difficulty finding the right colors without completely changing our color scheme.

My manager suggested we could just link to a high-contrast extension in Chrome or provide instructions on how to enable high-contrast in Windows and don't worry about meeting those requirements by default (all our users will be on Chrome in Windows).

I'm wondering if just instructing a user that needs a high-contrast mode, how they can enable it via external tools, is acceptable within WCAG 2.0.

Another option at the very least which I'm fairly sure must be okay, is to enable a toggle on our site for a high-contrast stylesheet that they can toggle on, still leaving the default mode that doesn't follow the rule.

#### Update:

After further research into this after posting this question, I can't find anywhere that mentions being able to use a third-party tool to avoid having to create a high-contrast version ourselves, which leads me to believe that this probably isn't allowed then.

The research along with @unor's response does tell me that I can provide a high-contrast mode that the user can enable, allowing the main version to remain as-is. As long as it is easily accessible by the user to toggle.

Thanks.

Comment: Related question regarding your last paragraph: [Having a separate accessible page for screen reader users](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/105064/17023)

Answer (score 1):

Use this tool http://wave.webaim.org/ to pick the right colors for your default design. It includes the contrast tool (3rd tab) that will help you pick the right colors. 
However, if new colors affect too much your design you may add high contrast modes at the top of your website.
Take a look here how they may be implemented on the website, this is the wordpress theme of the [WCAG wordpress themes provider](https://www.pixelemu.com/blog/web-development/build-website-small-business-wcag-compliance-wordpress), maybe you will find it helpful and this is how you may do on your website https://demo.pixelemu.com/pe-services-constructions-wcag/

Comment: You answer here seems to focus on the content of the links - Could you please rewrite it so that it would still be useful if the links should fail at a later date?